# How to remove border line from the linear layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have a dialog box with 2 layouts and an image in the second layout. I am using android constraint layout to keep my image, and the constraint layout is contained in a linear layout 
Below is my xml code.

```
android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"


android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"

    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagerte1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/menu_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Everything works fine but am trying to remove the line as seen in the image [image: this is the screenshot with the white border line am trying to remove]  how can I remove this line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line of code to do the same.

dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

*https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setBackgroundDrawableResource(int)*

Comment: The theme of the dialog box is Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen. Your method alters the theme, the dialog box is no longer full screen or has the screen black